# Uploading image and video into a form to create an object

Tags: node.js, image, file, upload

Hope you're doing well.

I have a question regarding my Node.js backend app. I am trying to upload an image and a video but I get this error :

"error": "Unexpected field" on postman

Here is my code :

```
create:(req,res)=>{
        console.log("Test1");
        
        console.log("Test1bis");
        //const exercise=JSON.parse(req.body.exercise);
        //delete exercise._id;
        console.log("Test2")
        var exerciseB = new Exercise({
            ...req.body,
            image:`${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/exercise/${req.file.filename1}`,
            video:`${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/videos/exercise/${req.file.filename2}`
        })
        console.log("Test3")

        exerciseB.save((err,exercise)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log("C'est le 2eme err");
                return res.status(500).json({
                    status:500,
                    message:err.message
                })
            }
            console.log("Ca arrive jusqu'au 200");
            return res.status(201).json({
                status:200,
                message:"Exercise Created Successfully !"
            })
        })
    }
```

And this is the multer file I am using to generate the image in a separate file ( I am using a similar multer for the video) :

```
const multer=require('multer');

const MIME_TYPES={
    'image/jpg':'jpg',
    'image/jpeg':'jpg',
    'image/png':'png'
}

const storage=multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,callback)=>{
            callback(null,'public/images/exercise');
    },
    filename1:(req,file,callback)=>{
        var name=Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(123456789)).toString();
        name+=Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(123456789)).toString();
        name+=Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(123456789)).toString();
        name+=Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(123456789)).toString();
        name+=Date.now()+".";
        const extension=MIME_TYPES[file.mimetype];
        name+=extension;

        callback(null,name)
    }



})

module.exports=multer({storage}).single('image');
```

And here is my postman screenshot :

[image]

This is my other multer file for the video :

```
const multer=require('multer');

const MIME_TYPES={
    'video/mp4':'mp4',
    'video/mpeg':'mpeg',
    'video/ogg':'ogv',
    'video/mp2t':'ts',
    'video//webm':'webm',


}

const storage=multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,callback)=>{
            callback(null,'public/videos/exercise');
    },
    filename2:(req,file,callback)=>{
        var name=Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(123456789)).toString();
        name+=Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(123456789)).toString();
        name+=Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(123456789)).toString();
        name+=Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(123456789)).toString();
        name+=Date.now()+".";
        const extension=MIME_TYPES[file.mimetype];
        name+=extension;

        callback(null,name)
    }



})

module.exports=multer({storage}).single('video');
```

And this is my routes file :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var exerciseController = require('../controllers/exerciseController');
const multerImage=require('../middlewares/multer-image');
const multerVideo=require('../middlewares/multer-video');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/show', exerciseController.show);

router.post('/create',multerImage, multerVideo, exerciseController.create);

router.put('/update/:id',multerImage, exerciseController.update);

module.exports = router;
```

I think I can't proceed the way I do in the routes file in the second router call.

Hope you can help me ! Thank you for trying too :)

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

```
module.exports=multer({storage}).single('image');
```

and set this line because image is not your name filename1/filename2 your image name

```
module.exports=multer({storage}).single('filename1');
```

This is running code but make sure you already created dir public/uploads, you edit your upload location and upload multiple file

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }))
app.use(express.static('public/uploads'))
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, "public/uploads")
   },
   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
   }
})
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
   const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('image_url');
   upload(req, res, function (err) {
      if (err) {
         console.log(err)
         return
      }
      var exerciseB = new Exercise({
         ...req.body,
         image: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/exercise/${req.file.originalname}`,
         video: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/videos/exercise/${req.file.originalname}`
      })
      exerciseB.save((err, exercise) => {
         if (err) {
            console.log("C'est le 2eme err");
            return res.status(500).json({
               status: 500,
               message: err.message
            })
         }
         console.log("Ca arrive jusqu'au 200");
         return res.status(201).json({
            status: 200,
            message: "Exercise Created Successfully !"
         })
      })
   })
})
app.listen(9001, () => {
   console.log(`listening on port ${9001}`)
});
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't change the output. Thank you regardless 

Comment: import multer from 'multer'

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, "public/uploads")
   },
   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
   }
})
export default multer({ storage: storage })

you create the above separate function and import your routes file 
like: 
import upload from '../utils/file.handler'

and pass it on your route like:

route.post('/upload/image', upload.single('image-name'), uploadController.uploadFunc)

"image-name" is your postman "image" key there you upload png.png

Comment: I did exactly what you told me and got the same error.